# How to decrypt AWS Elastic Transcoder HLS AES encryption video to play .m3u8?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, m3u8, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I use AWS elastic transcoder HLS AES content protection with `No Store` option to encrypt my .m3u8 file, as the following documentation says, it will automatically generate a set of Encryption Key, Encryption Key MD5 and Encryption Initialization Vector.

[HLS AES protection with no store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/content-protection.html)

I tried to hit ARN(which I specified in my Pipeline)with Encryption Key with aws-sdk’s KMS `decrypt` api, but got `InvalidCiphertextException` error.

[aws-sdk decrypt api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KMS.html#decrypt-property)

My question is, how can I decrypt the Encryption Key and get a actual key (which I called, a content key), used for play a .m3u8 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the solution! use AWS KMS `decrypt` and insert params as follows:

```
const kmsDecryptparams = {
  CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(dataKey,'base64'),
  EncryptionContext: {
      service: 'elastictranscoder.amazonaws.com'
  }
};
```

The official document doesn't answer any bit about it, but you can find some reference [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=703127&#703127).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way: When the Elastic Transcoder job with the No Store has finished, open the Job again and click on the lock next to any of the variant playlists. It shows the decryption value in a popup, which you can save as a file. This value is already decrypted.